# Unhandled exception type IOException at CorrectLogin();

Tags: java, function, filereader, ioexception

```
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==EnterLogin) {
    
        CorrectLogin();
    
}
    
}
private void CorrectLogin() throws IOException {
    String filename = ("accounts.txt");
    FileReader fr1= new FileReader (filename);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
     String accounts[][] = new String[10][2];
        for(int k=0 ; k<10; k++ ){ `
```

*reading in from an external txt file*
`String line = br1.readLine();
String split [] = line.split(",");
accounts [k][0] = split [0];
accounts [k][1] = split [1];

```
    System.out.println(accounts[1][1]);
}
}`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t actually ask a question.  I assume you want to know what to do about the error message in your title.

You can answer that question yourself by deciding what should happen if CorrectLogin cannot read accounts.txt for any reason (such as the file not existing).

I assume your application needs the user to log in before it can provide any more functionality, so you probably should show the user an error dialog, then refuse to proceed any further.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == EnterLogin) {
        try {
            CorrectLogin();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                EnterLogin.getTopLevelAncestor(),
                "Cannot log in.\n\n" + e,
                "Login Failure",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            // Application can't work without a login, so do not keep going.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```